# How to retrieve data from destination VC in CleanSwift?

Tags: swift, clean-architecture

I tried to send data from Source VC to Destination VC this way from source's **Router** class.

```
    func routeToDetail() {
        let detailVC = LiveScoreDetailContainerVC()
        guard let viewController = viewController,
              let dataStore = dataStore,
              var detailDataStore = detailVC.router?.dataStore else { return }
        passDataToDetail(source: dataStore, destination: &detailDataStore)
        navigateToDetail(source: viewController, destination: detailVC)
    }
    
    // MARK: Navigation
    
    func navigateToDetail(source: LiveScoreVC, destination: LiveScoreDetailContainerVC) {
        source.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    }
    
    // MARK: Passing data
    
    func passDataToDetail(source: LiveScoreListDataStore, destination: inout LiveScoreDetailContainerDataStore) {
        destination.data = source.data
        print(source.data)
    }
```

The data is successfully set at Destination's DataStore.

```
import UIKit

protocol LiveScoreDetailContainerBusinessLogic {
    func doSomething(request: LiveScoreDetailContainerModel.Request)
}

protocol LiveScoreDetailContainerDataStore {
    //var name: String { get set }
    var data: LiveScoreModels.LiveScores.Data { get set }
}

class LiveScoreDetailContainerInteractor: LiveScoreDetailContainerBusinessLogic, LiveScoreDetailContainerDataStore {
    
    var presenter: LiveScoreDetailContainerPresentationLogic?
    var worker: LiveScoreDetailContainerWorker?
    //var name: String = ""
    var data: LiveScoreModels.LiveScores.Data = LiveScoreModels.LiveScores.Data()
    
    // MARK: Do something
    func doSomething(request: LiveScoreDetailContainerModel.Request) {
        worker = LiveScoreDetailContainerWorker()
        worker?.doSomeWork()
        let response = LiveScoreDetailContainerModel.Response()
        presenter?.presentSomething(response: response)
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve that data from my destination VC to continue things.

Comment: What’s the confirming type of `LiveScoreDetailContainerDataStore`? You can read and mutate `data` in that type, `protocol` is jut a blueprint.

Comment: @TusharSharma  You mean the interactor? I'll update my post now.

Comment: I think you can absolutely use delegate pattern in this scenario. Declare LiveScoreDetailContainerDelegate, then set to current controller (which injected in source router)

Comment: @son, i want to know how datastore works.